# How to update table columns if another table columns are updated in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in SQL which have the following structure:

1) Doctors Table

```
DoctorId PendingCases OngoingCases CompletedCases
```

2) Cases Table

```
CaseId DoctorId CaseStatus
```

Inside the Cases Table, if the CaseStatus is set to 0, then it is a pending case, if it is set to 1, then it is an ongoing case and if it is set to 2 then it is a completed case.

So the number of pending cases for a doctor given his doctorid would be:

```
select count(*) as 'Pending Cases'
from Cases 
Where doctorid = '993883'
and casestatus = 0;
```

But I need this information to automatically update the three columns inside the doctor table. I know i have to use trigger, it will be good if you can demonstrate this.

Comment: This doesn't really fit into relational design and can cause all sorts of problems.  You shouldn't replicate data like this!

Comment: I agree @NigelRen For displaying the number of pending, ongoing and completed cases for every doctor, i should have directly called a query on the cases table. But I have already integrated the API in my application at multiple places and it would be difficult to go back. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't update the table, just use a view

```
CREATE VIEW doctors AS
SELECT
doctorId,
SUM(IF(casestatus = 0, 1, 0)) AS pending,
SUM(IF(casestatus = 1, 1, 0)) AS ongoing,
SUM(IF(casestatus = 2, 1, 0)) AS completed
FROM cases
GROUP BY doctorId;
```

Then you can query the view like

```
SELECT * FROM doctors WHERE doctorId = 993883;
```

Comment: Ahh, a rather nice way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how we can use triggers to update the columns:

```
create trigger updatedoctorscases
on cases
for insert, update, delete
as begin
    update doctors
    set pendingcases = (select count(*) from cases
    where casestatus = 0
    and doctors.doctorid = cases.doctorid);
    update doctors
    set ongoingcases = (select count(*) from cases
    where casestatus = 1
    and doctors.doctorid = cases.doctorid);
    update doctors
    set completedcases = (select count(*) from cases
    where casestatus = 2
    and doctors.doctorid = cases.doctorid);
end
```